# I need to know how to make a proper 4 bit binary counter

Tags: windows, logic, program-counter

I tried making a 4 bit binary counter from the following picture:

[image]
[image]

As the result of making that circuit in a game with no flip-flops or anything with are intended with blocks I was confused on the following:

- where is the output?
- does the clock speed matter?
- why doesn't it work?
- is this even right?

Comment: You forgot to add the pictures.

Comment: whoops ill add one more and that was a very fast response

Comment: i think i have to delete this ...